# Suppress blank page in sapthesis

Tags: blank-page, sapthesis

I edited this `sapthesis-template` adding some package but in the output a blank page appears between `\dedication` and `\tableofcontnts`. Why? And how could I do to suppress it?

My code

Thank you so much

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
\documentclass[binding=0.6cm]{sapthesis}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% My edit starts from following line...

\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{Gold1}}
\sectionfont{\color{Silver}}
\usepackage[notextcomp]{stix}
\usepackage[notext, nomath, not1, notextcomp, upint]{stix2}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}

% ... and finishes here.

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={La mia tesi},pdfauthor={Francesco Biccari}}
\title{La mia tesi}
\author{Francesco Biccari}
\IDnumber{123456}
\course{Laurea Magistrale in Fisica}
\courseorganizer{Facoltà di Scienze Matematiche, Fisiche e Naturali}
\AcademicYear{2021/2022}
\advisor{Prof. Caio}
\coadvisor{Dr. Sempronio}
\authoremail{francesco.biccari@pippo.com}
\copyyear{2022}
\thesistype{Tesi di Laurea Magistrale}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\dedication{Dedicato a\\ Donald Knuth}
\begin{abstract}
Questa tesi parla di me.
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduzione}
...
\backmatter
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection % Give this command only if hyperref is loaded
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
% Here put the code for the bibliography. You can use BibTeX or
% the BibLaTeX package or the simple environment thebibliography.
\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAIK `sapthesis` is a book class and so the default is `twoside`. The table of contents is a chapter and chapters in books usually start on right-hand pages. You could try either option `openany` or `oneside`. But if you use it for a thesis you should ask your Prof. before.